# Google Pay API using CyberSource Payment Gateway

Tags: android, kotlin, payment-gateway, google-pay, cybersource

I am trying to implement the Google Pay payment method in my mobile application using Cybersource Payment gateway. I refer [this example/tutorial](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial) for the reference and checked the implementation.

I configured the gateway name and merchant ID in the demo snippet and getting the success and Google Payment token in the success response. When i tried to implement the same code in my actual app I am getting the below error when I click on the Google Pay button.

> Request failed ; Unexpected error has occured,Please try again later.
> [OR_BIBED_01]

I checked the log and found that i got the below exception in the logcat but unable to resolve it.

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:
> at
> com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.TaskUtil.setResultOrApiException(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:4)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.internal.wallet.zzy.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet@@19.1.0:1)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.internal.wallet.zzt.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet@@19.1.0:33)
> at
> com.google.android.gms.internal.wallet.zzb.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet@@19.1.0:3)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)

This error comes in the `isReadyToPay()` method which check the availability of Google Pay. I am not able to understand that same code worked in the demo app/example and but not working in the my app.

Comment: are you able to share your code for me to have a look? Also, do you have the same problem when trying https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to add `meta-data` tag in Android manifest file. Once i added, it start working.

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
   android:value="true" />
```